# Derivative of the square root of a diagonal matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let the entries of the diagonal matrix $A \in R^{n\times n}$ are differentiable 
functions of $\theta$.

The matrix $A$ is:

\begin{bmatrix}
\theta & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \theta^3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & sin(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}

What is the derivative of $\sqrt{A}$ :

$$\frac{\partial \sqrt{A}}{\partial \theta} = ?$$

Comment: Is $\theta>0$? ${}$

Comment: yes copper.hat $\theta > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have  $$A=\text{diag }(\theta, \theta^3, \sin \theta)\Rightarrow \sqrt{A}=\text{diag }\left(\theta^{1/2}, \theta^{3/2}, \left(\sin \theta\right)^{1/2}\right)$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{d\theta}\sqrt{A}=\text{diag }\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}\theta^{1/2}, \frac{d}{d\theta}\theta^{3/2}, \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin \theta\right)^{1/2}\right)=\ldots$$ for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the three derivatives exist.